# Skip some part of code while executing in php to increase execution time

Tags: php, ajax

I'm executing a simple php script to insert near about 10-20 fields using php and it works fine, it's execution time is like 40ms. But now when i integrate sms and swift mail service it takes near about 8.40 to 10.2 seconds to execute. i want to increase the execution period, how can i get it done?

```
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $hostname='localhost';
  $username='root';
  $password='';

  try {
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=college",$username,$password);

  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
  $sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_city)
  VALUES ('".$_POST["stu_name"]."','".$_POST["stu_email"]."','".$_POST["stu_city"]."')";
    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
      echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";

      // this part of code takes a lot to execute
      $hello_form_submit_body = 'test mail';
      send_mail($hello_form_submit_subject, $_POST["stu_email", $_POST["stu_name"], $hello_form_submit_body, 'test mail', $hello_id, 'hello');

      /*send sms*/
      $sms_body = "Thank You, Your hello application has been submitted with ORDER ID (".$data_hello['hello_order_no']."), please complete your payment here (".$button_link.")";
      sms($data_hello['hello_mobile_no'], $sms_body, 'OLhello');


    }
    else{
      echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
    }

    $dbh = null;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}



/*Functions Used*/
function sms($number, $message, $sender_id){
  //code to send sms
}

function send_mail($subject, $to, $to_name, $body, $sender_name, $id, $service){
  //swift mailer code to send mail using smtp
}
```

is there any way that i can skip the execution time of that code and proceed with the rest execution like i dont care weather the sms is delivered or the mail is sent or not, i just want to increase the execution time with sms and mail send functions executed, or please suggest something like i will send a request to a file that will execute this functions and i will proceed without waiting for the response of that functions.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible to achieve, however, there is a workaround where you can save this function in a separate page and call it via `exec` and don't wait for a response

Comment: thanks @MoisheySchwartz can you please provide me the example how can i use exec e.g.: `exec(sms($data_hello['hello_mobile_no'], $sms_body, 'OLhello'));` is this what you want me to do?

Answer (score 0):

While there are many solutions, the simplest one is probably to fork your process and let child send mail and die while parent proceeds with the rest of the script

```
$sms_body = "Thank You, Your hello application has been submitted with ORDER ID (".$data_hello['hello_order_no']."), please complete your payment here (".$button_link.")";
  if(!pcntl_fork())
  {sms($data_hello['hello_mobile_no'], $sms_body, 'OLhello');
  exit;
  }
```